# How to create constraints that use expr() dynamically?

Tags: typo3-9.x

A user can enter a letter range like "A-D", by which a query must find all records that start with any of those letters. What I eventually need is a constraints block that looks like this:

```php
$constraints = [
    $query->expr()->eq(
        'composition.sys_language_uid',
        $query->createNamedParameter($language, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
    ),
    $query->expr()->orX(
        $query->expr()->like(
            'composition.title',
            $query->createNamedParameter('A%')
        ),
        $query->expr()->like(
            'composition.title',
            $query->createNamedParameter('B%')
        ),
        $query->expr()->like(
            'composition.title',
            $query->createNamedParameter('C%')
        ),
        $query->expr()->like(
            'composition.title',
            $query->createNamedParameter('D%')
        )
    )
];
```

which is a structure, that works well, when I use it as a test. So I know I need to strive for a solution like this.

But, of course, since the letters given are not fixed, but variable, the block within `->orX()` needs to be calculated programmatically. This is, where my problem lies.

I tried this:

```
// A custom helper function that splits a letter range string like "A-D"
// and returns an array like ['A','B','C','D'] 
$compareLetters = Helper::returnItemOrListAsArray($letter, true);
}

// Create the query
$query = $allDbConnections['composition']->createQueryBuilder();

// Collect constraints
$addConstraints = [];

// Compare first letter against given compareLetters
foreach($compareLetters as $l) {
    $addConstraints[] = $query->expr()->like(
        'composition.title',
        $query->createNamedParameter($l . '%')
    );
}
```

Trying to insert the resulting array like this:

```
$constraints = [
    $query->expr()->eq(
        'composition.sys_language_uid',
        $query->createNamedParameter($language, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
    ),
    $query->expr()->orX(
        implode(',', $addConstraints)
    )
]
```

throws an exception:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Currently I have no idea, how to do this differently nor how to interpret the exception. Any hint would be most welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it's a good approach, but I would try out `range()` function to generate the query, something like this:

```
<?php

$userInput = 'A-D';

list($start, $end) = explode('-', $userInput);

$selection = [];

foreach (range($start, $end) as $letter) {
    $selection[] = $query->expr()->like(
        'composition.title',
        $query->createNamedParameter($letter . '%')
    );
}

$constraints = [
    $query->expr()->eq(
        'composition.sys_language_uid',
        $query->createNamedParameter($language, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
    ),
    $query->expr()->orX(...$selection)
];
```

So more or less what you already did. Just you are not using the spread operator in your example when calling `orX()`